# HTML select option disabled

Tags: html, select

My option box is disabled in Chrome and Firefox. But it works on internet explorer?
  Can someone look at my code and tell me what I am doing wrong?  
Thanks

```html
<div class="col-lg-7 input-group">      
    <select id="globalSelect" class="form-control" style="background-color: white; color: grey;">
        <option>Quarterly</option>
        <option>Monthly</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: its appears normal, for me you are using a color equal disable. just it.

Comment: I think it just css style, but option are not really disabled, right click / inspect element to be sure.

Comment: I think I found the problem, I covered my col 7 where my option is with a col 12 where my graph is. I think its clicking on the larger col and thereby I can't reach my col 7.

Comment: What version of Internet Explorer are you using?

Comment: @user1438038 - I am using version 10.0.9200.16576

Answer (score 1):

So, firefox and chrome dont seem to fix the problem with overlapping col's. I added a br after my col7 so it wouldn't overlap with the col12 and it works!

```
<div id="global" class="tab-pane fade">
              <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-lg-7 input-group">

                      <select id="globalSelect" class="form-control" style="background-color: white; color: grey;">
                          <option>Quarterly</option>
                          <option>Monthly</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
              <div class="content container">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                      <div class="widget">
                        <div class="widget-header"> <i class="icon-bar-chart"></i>
                          <h3>Global turnover VAT incl.</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="widget-content">
                          <div id="chartGlobal" class="jqplot-chart" style="width:100%; height:350px"></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Thank you for all the comments.

Answer (score 0):

There's no error in your code
just check your chrome and firefox versions are up to date.

if you still having problem can you please give detailed code that would be helpful.

Comment: I found the problem Chrome and Firefox don't seem to handle the col problem. If I add a "<br />" then I can click the options. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you are looking for but I think browser version is not an issue here. As you are using basic elements of html and css.

Below are three different select elements that you may want to achieve.

```html
    
    Disabled: 
    <select id="globalSelect" class="form-control" disabled="true">
                <option>Quarterly</option>
                <option>Monthly</option>
    </select>

    <br/>
    <br/>

    Styled like disabled:
    <select id="globalSelect" class="form-control" style="background-color: white; color: grey;">
            <option>Quarterly</option>
            <option>Monthly</option>
    </select>


    <br/>
    <br/>

    Active:
    <select id="globalSelect" class="form-control">
                <option>Quarterly</option>
                <option>Monthly</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not disabling your option box, you simply set a different style that makes them *look disabled*. Depending on the software version you are using, Internet Explorer may or may not support styling `select` elements.

Try using the `disabled` attribute:

```
<select id="globalSelect" class="form-control">
  <option disabled="disabled" value="quarterly">Quarterly</option>
  <option disabled="disabled" value="monthly">Monthly</option>
</select>
```